# No such file or directory for zip file - kotlin android

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to read zip from zip file programitically.

```
 val f = File("src/main/files/zipfile.zip")
 val zis = ZipInputStream(FileInputStream(f))
```

but i got error.

> Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: src/main/files/zipfile.zip (No such file or directory)

Why it doesn't see this file if it is on this path?

Comment: `src/main/` usually represents a file on your development machine. That file is not on the device. If you are looking to package content in your app, unZIP that `zipfile.zip` into `src/main/assets/`. Then, use `getAssets()` on a `Context`, such as your `Activity`, to get an `AssetManager`. From there, you can access the assets that you placed into `src/main/assets/`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not on this path in your compiled app. That's not a valid asset directory, and the files there will not be in your compiled app.

If you want to include a raw file in your app, put it in `src/main/assets`. And to read it, you need to get it via `context.assets`

For example, in a Fragment:

```
val zipFileStream = requireContext().assets.open("zipfile.zip")
val zis = ZipInputStream(zipFileStream)
```

although you most likely should be reading files in a ViewModel so the contents can persist through a screen rotation.